# Type '{ [x: number]: any; }' is missing the following properties from Pick<T, keyof T>

Tags: typescript, react-typescript, type-assertion

I have this code

```js
interface FormState {
    cardNumber: string,
    month: string,
    year: string
}
```

```js
    handleInputChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<MaskedInput>) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    };
```

TypeScript doesn't know what the `name` property of `event.target` is, but I know that it will always match the `FormState` keys. Similarly with the `value` property.

I tried to fix it with type assertion but still get the error

```js
type ObjectKey<T> = keyof T;
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

[event.target.name as ObjectKey<FormState>]: event.target.value as ValueOf<FormState>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the type for target name in React.ChangeEvent:

```
handleInputChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{name: keyof FormState}>) => {
```

Since you are handling input change, the better type will be `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`:

```
type TargetName=keyof FormState
const handleInputChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    let name = event.target.name as TargetName
    name===''
};
```